# Complexity in Java

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a general question about my complexity in my Code. Since I am doing some things from Codeforces, complexity matters the first time to me.
Problemset: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1554/A

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Collections;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doCalculation();
    }

    public static void doCalculation () {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        long n = sc.nextLong();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int numbersInRow = sc.nextInt();
            long [] numbersToRead = new long[numbersInRow];
            for(int j = 0; j < numbersInRow; j++) {
                numbersToRead[j] = sc.nextLong();
            }

            long maxMultiplication = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < numbersInRow; k++) {
                for (int m = k + 1; m < numbersInRow; m++) {
                    //Von jetzt an von 1 bis 2; von 1 bis 3; von 2 bis 3
                    long[] subarray = subArray(numbersToRead, k, m);
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subarray));

                    long min = Arrays.stream(subarray).min().getAsLong();
                    //System.out.println(min);

                    long max = Arrays.stream(subarray).max().getAsLong();
                    //System.out.println(max);

                    long multiplicationEveryArray = min * max;

                    if(multiplicationEveryArray > maxMultiplication) {
                        maxMultiplication = multiplicationEveryArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(maxMultiplication);
        }
    }
    
    public static long[] subArray(long[] array, int beg, int end) {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, beg, end + 1);
    } 
}
```

I think copyRange has complexity O(n) and subarry has the same complexity.
What are some ways to improve my complexity without taking a different approach?

Comment: If the code works as expected, the question might be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, these problems are set up in a way that the brute-force method will finish in a million years.

Looking at the examples, my first intuition kind of was that you only need to look at neighboring numbers, making this an O(n) problem.

If you have `f(1,2)` and `f(2,3)` then `f(1,3)` will definitely be the max of `f(1,2)` and `f(2,3)`. The product of the first and last elements is impossible to be the max as it means that at least one of them has to be smaller than or equal to the second element in the middle to be considered, making the product smaller than or equal to the product of "just neighbors".

You can continue on through induction to reach to the conclusion that `f(1,n+1)` will be `max(f(1,2), f(2,3), ... f(n,n+1))`.

In order to get rid of the O(n^2) loop try

```
for(int k = 0; k < numbersInRow - 1; k++) {
  final int product = numbersToRead[k] * numbersToRead[k+1];
  if (product > maxMultiplication) {
    maxMultiplication = product;
  }
}
```

Comment: Creat answer, thank you!
I did not see, that I do not need to check f(1, 3) if I already checked f(1,2) and f(2,3)!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problem with this code :

I think you are using too much space for this question. In this question why are you always creating a new array before finding out max and min.
And that too in a loop so it will cause memory problems for sure later.
As approximately space complexity will go above O(n2)

```
long[] subarray = subArray(numbersToRead, k, m);
long min = Arrays.stream(subarray).min().getAsLong();
long max = Arrays.stream(subarray).max().getAsLong();
```

First of all you are doing all this in 3n time ( O(n) for copying +O(n) for finding minimum, O(n) for finding maximum )

i suggest if possible find a better algorithm which can find maximum and minimum in O(n) time if possible.

If thats not possible try finding maximum , minimum in a single loop and try avoiding this function of yours.

```
public static long[] subArray(long[] array, int beg, int end) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(array, beg, end + 1);
}
```

Instead of creating a new array everytime try iterating on the same array.
Avoid streams if you dont have anykind of function which can iterate on original array without creating a new one though i doubt so, that would be the case. I think there is some kind of function which can help limit the finding of minimum and maximum on some range of array

Something like :

```
Arrays.stream(numbersToRead).range(k, m)
```